# MySQL: Guarantee Results, Decimal Issue

Tags: mysql, decimal

I have a table with the following attributes:

```
MyTable:
- double longitude 
- double latitude
- varchar place_id
- varcar geoJSON_string
```

Given some point having a longitude `x` and latitude `y` I need to select the `k` closest points.

I know I tack a `LIMIT k` on the end of the query, but is there a way I can guarantee at least `k` points from a database of `~250,000` records?

Also, how would I even query the decimal values? I need to select something similar to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE latitude=140.3**** and longitude=132.2**** LIMIT k;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE latitude BETWEEN '140.3' AND '140.4' AND longitude BETWEEN '132.2' AND '132.3' LIMIT k;
```

or, if you need the best result :

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY ABS(ABS(searched-lon - longitude) - ABS(searched-lat - latitude)) ASC LIMIT k;
```

Comment: +1 for the first query (I'd change a bit `BETWEEN` start interval to cover initial value - 0.1). The second query (in my opinion) will produce a greater overhead - no indexes will be used even if they exist.